# Selenium Grid Headless Parallel

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium grid to scrape thousands of pages since all the pages are heavily populated by Javascript.

I found this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium/selenium_grids.htm) which gave me a pretty good idea of how to set up Selenium grid and run script in parallel. However, my situation is a little different.

(1) I only want one type of browser, like Chrome(or Firefox), but I want to run as many as possible.

(2) To make sure this solution scale, I probably will use some Cloud service where the code will be running in Linux environment.

So here is my question:

Do I have to use TestNG/Junit frame work to run the code in parallel? If I run the code in multiple processes, all making requests to the same hub, will the hub coordinate them out of box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1) I only want one type of browser, like Chrome(or Firefox), but I
>   want to run as many as possible.

You should be running not as many possible, but a heuristic number, that just works for you. The reason being is, running like 30 chrome browsers at a time can give you unpredictable results.

> (2) To make sure this solution scale, I probably will use some Cloud
>   service where the code will be running in Linux environment.

You can look at [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/)

> Do I have to use TestNG/Junit frame work to run the code in parallel?

Thats upto you. As far as your creating the `driver` in multiple threads your fine. If your using your own FW, then you can create Thread pool and start creating the `driver` from each thread pool.

> If I run the code in multiple processes, all making requests to the
>   same hub, will the hub coordinate them out of box?

Yes Selenium Hub will be co-ordinating this for you, out of the box. You no need to worry about anything here.

Comment: I know that everyone says running "tons of chrome browsers can give you unpredictable results", but how? What happens?